# How can i replace react-swipeable since the are not compatible in React v18

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I trying to use a material UI component but react-swipeable dependencies are no longer compatible with React v 18 but I need to get replace the react-swipeable dependencies since the are no longer work whit React 18, what can I do ?

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
    import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
    import MobileStepper from '@mui/material/MobileStepper';
    import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft';
    import KeyboardArrowRight from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
    import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
    import { autoPlay } from 'react-swipeable-views-utils';

    const AutoPlaySwipeableViews = autoPlay(SwipeableViews);

    const images = [
      {
        label: 'San Francisco – Oakland Bay Bridge, United States',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537944434965-cf4679d1a598?auto=format&fit=crop&',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bird',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538032746644-0212e812a9e7?auto=format&fit=crop&',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bali, Indonesia',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537996194471-e657df975ab4?auto=format&fit=crop&',
      },
      {
        label: 'Goč, Serbia',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512341689857-198e7e2f3ca8?auto=format&fit=crop&',
      },
    ];

    function SwipeableTextMobileStepper() {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
      const maxSteps = images.length;
    
      const handleNext = () => {
        setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
      };
    
      const handleBack = () => {
        setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
      };
    
      const handleStepChange = (step: number) => {
        setActiveStep(step);
      };
    
      return (
        <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 400, flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <Paper
            square
            elevation={0}
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              height: 50,
              pl: 2,
              bgcolor: 'background.default',
            }}
          >
            <Typography>{images[activeStep].label}</Typography>
          </Paper>
          <AutoPlaySwipeableViews
            axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
            index={activeStep}
            onChangeIndex={handleStepChange}
            enableMouseEvents
          >
            {images.map((step, index) => (
              <div key={step.label}>
                {Math.abs(activeStep - index) <= 2 ? (
                  <Box
                    component="img"
                    sx={{
                      height: 255,
                      display: 'block',
                      maxWidth: 400,
                      overflow: 'hidden',
                      width: '100%',
                    }}
                    src={step.imgPath}
                    alt={step.label}
                  />
                ) : null}
              </div>
            ))}
          </AutoPlaySwipeableViews>
          <MobileStepper
            steps={maxSteps}
            position="static"
            activeStep={activeStep}
            nextButton={
              <Button
                size="small"
                onClick={handleNext}
                disabled={activeStep === maxSteps - 1}
              >
                Next
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowLeft />
                ) : (
                  <KeyboardArrowRight />
                )}
              </Button>
            }
            backButton={
              <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowRight />
                ) : (
                  <KeyboardArrowLeft />
                )}
                Back
              </Button>
            }
          />
        </Box>
      );
    }
    export default SwipeableTextMobileStepper;
```

As I said at the beginning of my message, I need to get rid of the dependencies of react-swipeable-views-utils since they are not compatible with React version code, how can I replace them so that the component continues to work as it should.

Answer (score 3):

- `import SwipeableViews from "react-swipeable-views-react-18-fix"`;
- Replace `AutoPlaySwipeableViews` into `SwipeableViews`
- For autoplay

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

  ```
     setTimeout(() => {
       setActiveStep(
         activeStep === images.length - 1 ? 0 : activeStep + 1
       );
     }, 2000);
  ```
- Add that activeStep in SwipeableViews `<SwipeableViews index={activeStep}>`